# How to make Python REGEX match first occurrence of the expression - it extends to the second now

Tags: python, regex

I have to following text:

```
Signatures 35 2 Table of Contents Part I. Financial Information Item 1. Financial  
 Statements Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Statements of Operations and    Comprehensive Income (in thousands except per unit amounts unaudited) Three   Months Ended March 31 2018 2017 Revenues Midstream Services - Affiliate 64263
 50314 Midstream Services -  Net Income Attributable
 to Limited Partners Per Limited Partner Unit - Basic and Diluted Common Units
 0.97 0.77 Subordinated Units 0.97 0.77 Weighted Average Limited Partner Units
 Outstanding - Basic Common Units 23683 15903 Subordinated Units 15903 15903
 Weighted Average Limited Partner Units Outstanding - Diluted Common Units 23698
 15909 Subordinated Units 15903 15903 The accompanying notes are an integral part
 of these financial statements. 3 Table of Contents Noble Midstream Partners LP
 758 The accompanying notes are an integral part of these financial statements.
 4 Table of Contents Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Statements of Cash
 Flows (in thousands unaudited) Three Months Ended March 31 2018 2017 Cash Flows
 From Operating Activities Net Income 39136 34520 Adjustments to Reconcile Net
 Income to Net Cash Provided by Operating Activities Depreciation and 
Amortization 11329 2449 Dividends from Equity Method Investee Net of Income 393 0
 Unit-Based Compensation 321 127 Other Adjustments for Noncash Items Included in
 Income 167 95 Changes in Operating Assets and Liabilities Net of Assets Acquired
 and Liabilities Assumed Increase in Accounts Receivable (2520) (3322) Decrease 
in Accounts Payable (836) (2518) Other Operating Assets and Liabilities Net
 (2387) 874 Net Cash Provided by Operating Activities 45603 32225 Cash Flows 
From Investing Activities Additions to Property Plant and Equipment (161509)
 (32298) Black Diamond Acquisition Net of Cash Acquired (650131) 0 Additions to
 Investments 0 (414) Distributions from Cost Method Investee 419 123 Net Cash 
Used in Investing Activities (811221) (32589) Cash Flows From Financing 
Activities Distributions to Noncontrolling Interests (3007) (11267) Contributions
 from Noncontrolling Interests 409865 7087 Borrowings Under Revolving Credit 
Facility 405000 0 Repayment of Revolving Credit Facility (55000) 0 Distributions
 to Unitholders (19860) (13782) Revolving Credit Facility Amendment Fees and 
Other (1987) (236) Net Cash Provided by (Used in) Financing Activities 735011 
(18198) Decrease in Cash Cash Equivalents and Restricted Cash (30607) (18562)
 Cash Cash Equivalents and Restricted Cash at Beginning of Period 55531 57421
 Cash Cash Equivalents and Restricted Cash at End of Period 24924 38859 The
 accompanying notes are an integral part of these financial statements. 5 Table
 of Contents Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Statement of Changes in 
Equity (in thousands unaudited) Partnership Common Units Subordinated Units 
General Partner Noncontrolling Interests
```

I need to extract text after words `Subordinated units` with four numbers that follow this combination of words and until **first** `Cash Flow`. I have constructed the following Regex:

```
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS? OF OPERATIONS?.+?\sSubordinated units.+?\s(\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?)
```

This regex should not find any match as there are only two numbers after expression `Subordinated units`. However, it manages to match till the end of this `Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Statements of Cash Flows (in thousands unaudited) Three Months Ended March 31 2018 2017` which has three numbers, and is second occurrence of `Cash Flow`. How do I make sure that it catches only exact four numbers and does not extend to the second `Cash Flow`?

Comment: Square brackets define *character classes*. Each character class matches exactly one character, with no regard to ordering. So, `[abc]` matches either `a`, `b` or `c`; `[^abc]` matches exactly one character that is *not* `a`, `b` or `c`.

Comment: ...so, your `[^Cash flows]` matches exactly one character that is not a member of the set `C`, `a`, `s`, `h`... -- and then the `*` modifies it to match zero or more such characters.

Comment: I tried to group them as ```[^(Cash Flow)]``` - does not help.

Comment: Of course not, because the square brackets still are making it a class. **Stop using them.** They are simply entirely wrong in every respect for what you are trying to do.

Comment: What's the right way then?

Comment: Right way to do *what*? To match any string that isn't exactly `Cash Flow`? Python's regex syntax has negative assertions; take a look at them.

Comment: To match a string until it hits ```Cash Flow```.

Comment: `(.*?)Cash Flow` -- the `?` modifies the `*` to be non-greedy, so it only matches the shortest possible substring.

Comment: It does not help - it goes all the way to the second ```Cash Flow``` for some reason.

Comment: It works just fine in isolation -- build an isolated, narrow, simplified test case and a new question about it might be on-topic here.

Comment: I presented specific question here. If your suggestion does not work, it's not a reason to dismiss my question.

Comment: ...as you can see, `re.match('^(.*?)Cash Flow', 'First Cash Flow Second Cash Flow').groups()` returns only `'First '`. The suggestion works fine when applied in isolation. Your "specific" question is a huge, hairy regex that's far more complicated than the kind of narrow question we ask for, which should isolate only a single problem and remove everything unrelated.

Comment: ...in this case, your "specific" question was about square bracket syntax, and whatever problems you still have after applying my suggestion no longer have anything to do with square brackets.

Comment: I need to modify my original Regex to include negation of ```Cash Flow``` which I did incorrect with brackets originally.

Comment: Right, but "modify my original regex" is no more guaranteed to be in-scope than "please fix my program for me" is; if you identify a *specific, narrow problem* with your program (or your regex), visible after everything unrelated is factored out, we'll fix it for you. But it needs to be a single, specific, isolated issue; once you have several issues entangled, the question and its answer becomes less helpful to others, since people are unlikely to have the same combinations of separate issues.

Comment: In this case, simplifying your data (and your regex) to make that issue clear makes it easier to help you, and easier for others to learn from the help you're given.

Comment: Ok, I will edit this question.

Comment: @user3151858 The issue might be  that the string you posted contains line feed characters (also between "Cash" and "Flow") and hence you should either remove them (`.replace('\n', '')`) or modify the suggested regex as `'^(.*?)Cash\s+Flow'`.

Comment: @a_guest I have edited question to more narrowly define the problem. Hope it is more clear what I am trying to achieve. I have tried your suggestion and it did not work. There are no ```\n```.

Comment: @user3151858 I'm not sure it's clearer now. If you want to match four digits you can do so via `\d{4}`. If you want to match four (positive, integer) numbers then you can use `\d+(?: \d+){3}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this regex might solve your problem. It searches until the first `Cash Flows`.

It uses the `(?s)` modifier to let the `dot .` match newlines. Think of `s` in this case as *string* rather than matching a *line*.

At first, I was capturing up to the second `Cash Flows`, but I noticed that the first occurrence had a newline between *Cash* and *Flows*. To correct for this, I wrote `Cash\s+Flows` where the 2 words were separated by *space* (could be a regular space *or* a newline which is also a space character).

```
import re

fin = open('cash_flow.txt', 'r')

text = fin.read()

p = re.compile(r'(?s)(Consolidated Statements of Operations.+?Cash\s+Flows)')

m = p.search(text)

print(m.group(1))
```

The print out I got was:

```
Consolidated Statements of Operations and    Comprehensive Income (in thousands except per unit amounts unaudited) Three   Months Ended March 31 2018 2017 Revenues Midstream Services - Affiliate 64263
 50314 Midstream Services - Third Party 11360 0 Crude Oil Sales - Third Party
 22110 0 Total Revenues 97733 50314 Costs and Expenses Cost of Crude Oil Sales
 21439 0 Direct Operating 17148 11401 Depreciation and Amortization 11329 2449
 General and Administrative 10442 2742 Total Operating Expenses 60358 16592
 Operating Income 37375 33722 Other (Income) Expense Interest Expense Net of
 Amount Capitalized 1033 267 Investment Income (2868) (1065) Total Other Income
 (1835) (798) Income Before Income Taxes 39210 34520 Income Tax Provision 74 0
 Net Income 39136 34520 Less: Net (Loss) Income Attributable to Noncontrolling
 Interests (225) 10178 Net Income Attributable to Noble Midstream Partners LP
 39361 24342 Less: Net Income Attributable to Incentive Distribution Rights 819 0
 Net Income Attributable to Limited Partners 38542 24342 Net Income Attributable
 to Limited Partners Per Limited Partner Unit - Basic and Diluted Common Units
 0.97 0.77 Subordinated Units 0.97 0.77 Weighted Average Limited Partner Units
 Outstanding - Basic Common Units 23683 15903 Subordinated Units 15903 15903
 Weighted Average Limited Partner Units Outstanding - Diluted Common Units 23698
 15909 Subordinated Units 15903 15903 The accompanying notes are an integral part
 of these financial statements. 3 Table of Contents Noble Midstream Partners LP
 758 The accompanying notes are an integral part of these financial statements.
 4 Table of Contents Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Statements of Cash
 Flows
```

Comment: I actually modified question as suggested by Charles Duffy to better define the problem. What I truly need is to extract only in case there are four digits after the expression ```Subordinated units```. I used expression ```Cash Flow``` as poor substitute for that. Your solution works - thank you. I just really want now to address the problem as it's defined - by selecting all text including four numbers after ```Subordinated units``` and not find anything if I have two numbers as in this case.

Comment: @user3151858 Do you want to begin capturing at `Consolidated Statements of Operations` or at `Subordinated Units` plus four numbers (there are only 2 in this case, so  should the match fail?

Comment: yes, I would like to extract from "Consolidated Statements of Operations``` to ```Subordinated units``` and two numbers that follow it. So the end could be either ``` Consolidated Statements of Cash Flow``` or even ```accompanying notes```. I need to fully extract the ```Statement of Operations```.

Comment: Yes, my match should ```Fail``` in this case as my search has four numbers but it does not.

Comment: @user3151858 `p = re.compile(r'(?s)(Consolidated Statements of Operations.+?Subordinated Units(?: \d+){4})')`  ???

Comment: What does ```?:``` do?

Comment: @user3151858 Do you mean `(?:\s\d+){4}`  That just clusters a group to apply the quantity to, `{4}`

Comment: I thought ```(....)``` does clustering? It works with one small problem - it select only 3 numbers not four for the case when I have four numbers and ```Fails``` as it should when I have two numbers. I am using the following to select numbers ```(?:\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s){4,4}```

Comment: Fixed my small problem by having: ```Subordinated units\s(?:\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s){4,4}```